# PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() but XML object looks fine

Tags: php, simplexml

I've created a SimpleXMLElement as follows:

```
$catSearchXml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.$categoryContainer);
```

When I then try to loop round the values using:

```
foreach ( $catSearchXML->categoryHistogram as $searchCategory )
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

When I do a `var_dump($catSearchXml)` I get the following:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (1) {
    ["categoryHistogram"]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (4) {
            ["categoryId"]=> string(3) "293" 
            ["categoryName"]=> string(14) "Sound & Vision" 
            ["count"]=> string(3) "123" 
            ["childCategoryHistogram"]=> array(8) { 
                [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (3) { 
                    ["categoryId"]=> string(5) "14969" 
                    ["categoryName"]=> string(27) "Home Audio & HiFi Separates" 
                    ["count"]=> string(2) "89" 
                }
                [1]=> etc...
```

When I check `is_array($catSearchXml->categoryHistogram)` it equals false

The following returns nothing: `$catSearchXML->categoryHistogram[0]->categoryName`

Any thoughts as this is doing my head in???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks man - sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself here, but you've defined `$catSearchXml`, and you're trying to loop over `$catSearchXML`. PHP variable names are case-sensitive.